# Using Python to search google and store the websites into variables

Tags: python, search

I looking for a way to search google with python and store each website into a slot in an data list. Im looking for something like the example code below.

```
search=input('->')
results=google.search((search),(10))
print results
```

In this case i want it to search google for whatever is in the variable "search", 10 is the amount of results I want to store in the variable and finally putting them on the screen with the "print results".

I would appreciate any help or anything similar to what I want. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Have you looked at google's search API and what it returns?

Comment: https://breakingcode.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/google-search-python/ ive tried the things here. The library didnt work for me. I got an error on launch.

Comment: Yup. Google's search API has been deprecated. You'll need an alternative.

Comment: Got any ideas? Another library perhaps?

Comment: Google provides [Google Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) but you'll have to shell out some shekels for anything useful (i.e. for more than 100 queries a day)

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview. You could also search here: https://www.programmableweb.com/category/search/apis?search_id=141502&category=20055. I believe Bing is a good, free alternative.

Comment: Alright thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above google does provide an api for completing searches (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview), and as mentioned depending on what you are trying to accomplish can get quite expensive. Another option is to scrap the google page. Below is an example I created using Beautiful Soup (https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) to scrap the google result.

import urllib2
    import xml.etree.ElementTree
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #install using 'pip install beautifulsoup4'

```
'''
Since spaces will not work in url parameters, the spaces have to be converted int '+'
ex) "example text" -> "example+text"  
'''
def spacesToPluses(string):
    words = string.split(" ")
    convertedString = ""
    for i in range(0, len(words)):
        convertedString += words[i] + "+"
    return convertedString[0:len(convertedString)-1]

'''
Opens the url with the parameter included and reads it as a string
'''
def getRawGoogleResponse(url):
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7' 
    headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,} #Required for google to allow url request

    request=urllib2.Request(url,None,headers) 
    response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    rawResponse = response.read()
    return rawResponse

'''
Takes in the raw string representation and converts it into an easier to navigate object (Beautiful Soup)
'''
def getParsedGoogleResponse(url):
    rawResponse = getRawGoogleResponse(url)
    fullPage = BeautifulSoup(rawResponse, 'html.parser')
    return fullPage

'''
Finds all of the urls on a single page
'''
def getGoogleResultsOnPage(fullPage):
    searchResultContainers = fullPage.find_all("h3", {"class": "r"}) #the results are contained in an h3 element with the class 'r'
    pageUrls = []
    for container in searchResultContainers: #get each link in the container
        fullUrl = container.find('a')['href']
        beginningOfUrl = fullUrl.index('http')
        pageUrls.append(fullUrl[beginningOfUrl:])#Chops off the extra bits google adds to the url
    return pageUrls

'''
Returns number of pages (max of 10)
'''
def getNumPages(basePage):
    navTable = basePage.find("table", {"id" : "nav"}) #The nav table contains the number of pages (up to 10)
    pageNumbers = navTable.find_all("a", {"class" : "fl"})
    lastPageNumber = int(pageNumbers[len(pageNumbers)-2].text)
    return lastPageNumber

'''
Loops through pages gathering url from each page
'''
def getAllGoogleSearchResults(search, numResults):
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + spacesToPluses(search)
    basePage = getParsedGoogleResponse(baseUrl)
    numPages = getNumPages(basePage)
    allUrls = []
    for i in range(0, numPages):
        completeUrl = baseUrl + "&start=" + str(i * 10) #google uses the parameter 'start' to represent the url to start at (10 urls pre page)
        page = getParsedGoogleResponse(completeUrl)
        for url in getGoogleResultsOnPage(page):
            allUrls.append(url)
    return allUrls[0:numResults]#return just the number of results


def main():
    print(getAllGoogleSearchResults("even another test", 1))

main()
```

The solution works for the first 10 pages (or next highest) of google results. The urls are returned in an array of string objects. The information is scrapped by getting the response using urllib2. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Google search page has maximum 10 number of results to return(by default), [parameter `num`](https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters-pagination-num) in [parameters `dict`](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) is responsible for this:

```py
params = {
    "q": query,          # query
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "us",          # country of the search, US -> USA
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}
```

To get more data, you can paginate through all pages using an infinite `while` loop. Pagination is possible as long as the next button exists (determined by the presence of a button selector on the page, in our case the CSS selector `.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext])`, you need to increase the value of `["start"]` by 10 to access the next page, if present, otherwise, we need to exit the while loop:

```py
if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break
```

You also need to pay attention to the fact that most sites, including Google, do not like being scraped and the request might be blocked if you using `requests` as default `user-agent in requests` library is a [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814). Additional step could be to [rotate `user-agent`](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#rotate-user-agents), for example, to switch between PC, mobile, and tablet, as well as between browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Edge and so on.

Check code in [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-search-with-pagination-bs4#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml


query = input("Input your query: ")    # for example: "auto"

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls
params = {
    "q": query,          # query
    "hl": "en",          # language
    "gl": "us",          # country of the search, US -> USA
    "start": 0,          # number page by default up to 0
    #"num": 100          # parameter defines the maximum number of results to return.
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

page_num = 0

website_data = []

while True:
    page_num += 1
    print(f"page: {page_num}")
        
    html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')
    
    for result in soup.select(".tF2Cxc"):
        title = f'Title: {result.select_one("h3").text}'
        link = f'Link: {result.select_one("a")["href"]}'
                    
        website_data.append({
              "title" : title,
              "link" : link,   
        })
      
    if soup.select_one('.d6cvqb a[id=pnnext]'):
        params["start"] += 10
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(website_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "title": "Title: Show Your Auto",
    "link": "Link: http://www.showyourauto.com/vehicles/388/2002-ford-saleen-mustang-s281-extreme-speedster"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title: Global Competition in the Auto Parts Industry: Hearings ...",
    "link": "Link: https://books.google.com/books?id=dm7bjDjkrRQC&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=auto&source=bl&ots=sIf4ELozPN&sig=ACfU3U3xea1-cJl9hiQe8cpac2KLrIF20g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWn7ukv6P7AhU3nGoFHSRxABY4jgIQ6AF6BAgEEAM"
  },
  {
    "title": "Title: Issues relating to the domestic auto industry: hearings ...",
    "link": "Link: https://books.google.com/books?id=fHX_MJobx3EC&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=auto&source=bl&ots=jcrwR-jwck&sig=ACfU3U0p0Wn6f-RU11U8Z0GtqMjTKd44ww&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjWn7ukv6P7AhU3nGoFHSRxABY4jgIQ6AF6BAgaEAM"
  },
  # ...
]
```

---

You can also use [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with the free plan.
The difference is that it will bypass blocks (including CAPTCHA) from Google, no need to create the parser and maintain it.

Code example:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, parse_qsl
import json, os

query = input("Input your query: ")  # for example: "auto"

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),   # serpapi key
  "engine": "google",                # serpapi parser engine
  "q": query,                        # search query
  "num": "100"                       # number of results per page (100 per page in this case)
  # other search parameters: https://serpapi.com/search-api#api-parameters
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)      # where data extraction happens

organic_results_data = []
page_num = 0

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()    # JSON -> Python dictionary
    
    page_num += 1
    
    for result in results["organic_results"]:
        organic_results_data.append({
            "page_num": page_num,
            "title": result.get("title"),
            "link": result.get("link"),
            "displayed_link": result.get("displayed_link"),   
        })
    
    if "next_link" in results.get("serpapi_pagination", []):
        search.params_dict.update(dict(parse_qsl(urlsplit(results.get("serpapi_pagination").get("next_link")).query)))
    else:
        break
    
print(json.dumps(organic_results_data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Output:

```json
[
   {
    "page_num": 4,
    "title": "San Francisco's JFK Drive to Remain Closed to Cars",
    "link": "https://www.nbcbayarea.com/decision-2022/jfk-drive-san-francisco-election/3073470/",
    "displayed_link": "https://www.nbcbayarea.com › decision-2022 › jfk-driv..."
  },
  {
    "page_num": 4,
    "title": "Self-Driving Cruise Cars Are Expanding to Most of SF, Says ...",
    "link": "https://sfstandard.com/business/self-driving-cruise-cars-are-expanding-to-most-of-sf-says-ceo/",
    "displayed_link": "https://sfstandard.com › business › self-driving-cruise-c..."
  },
  # ...
]
```